# Difficulty with using contextual parameters in for loop, in JSRender

Tags: for-loop, parameters, jsrender

I'm using JSRender 1.0.5, and the docs on this page: https://www.jsviews.com/#contextualparams
suggest I can do this:
"A contextual parameter is defined by simply writing ~myValue=... (for any expression) on any block tag, such as {{if}} or {{for}}."

But when I use it on a for loop, I cannot get it to work. I've spent hours on this - very frustrating.

```
{{for data.collection ~collectionIdx=#getIndex()}}
    <div id="someDiv">Index = {{:~collectionIdx}}</div>
{{/for}}
```

What I really want to do is pass the index of the outer loop into an inner loop, but I can't even get the basic functionality to work. If I spit out `{{:#getIndex()}}` inside the loop, it works fine - I just can't assign it to a contextual parameter.

What's the fix?

Answer (score 0):

[`#index`](https://www.jsviews.com/#viewobject@index), or `#getIndex()` return the index of an ['item view'](https://www.jsviews.com/#views@itemview) - when your context is within a `{{for someArray}}` which loops over an array.

But if you are not within a loop (over an array) the `#index` is `undefined` so renders as an empty string...

In your example your contextual parameter, `~collectionIdx=#getIndex()` is in the outer context, so it stores the value `undefined`.

But if you have nested loops then it will correctly render the index values at the appropriate level:

```
{{for outerArray}}
    {{for innerArray ~collectionIdx=#getIndex()}}
        <div>Outer Index = {{:~collectionIdx}}</div>
        <div>Inner Index = {{:#getIndex()}}</div>
    {{/for}}
{{/for}}
```

Comment: Except it doesn't. I have tried everything. If I refer to {{:#getIndex()}} within the loop, it gives the index. If I try to assign ~collectionIdx=#getIndex(), it is empty. I've even tried defining parameters like ~test="string" and {{:~test}} comes up empty. Contextual parameters simply are not picking up any values. When I look at the compiled template, I see references like view.hlp("test"), like it's looking for them in the helper.

Comment: Here's where it's not working (#data is an object):
`{{for outerArray}}  
  {{for #data ~collectionIdx=#getIndex() tmpl="tpl-inner-template" /}}  
{{/for}}  
  
<script id="tpl-inner-template" type="text/x-jsrender">  
  <div>Outer index = {{:~collectionIdx}}</div>  
</script>`

Comment: First thing - when you are using a platform that you don't yet know well, and something doesn't do what you expect, start from the assumption that you are missing something, rather than declaring that the platform itself does not work. (Sorry, but to declare that is actually both naive, and a bit arrogant). I will change the title of this question accordingly. Secondly, if you put `tmpl="#tpl-inner-template" then your new sample does work. [Here it is](https://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/fox4d0ym/).

Comment: Ad hominems aside, you do not know the environment I'm using JSRender in. We have a loader that loads template files and parses the script tags to define the templates using $.templates(id, html); where id = template id and html is the template. Therefore, tmpl="tpl-inner-template" works, and has been working, for a couple of years now. Just not with contextual parameters. Looks like a bug to me. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfau8djm/2/) that better illustrates my usage ... and it works. So I dug deeper and found the problem was in the code I was working with. The developer who wrote it initially rendered the UI in a {{for}} loop, then for some reason, in the code, removed each of the rendered instances and re-rendered them individually, so the #index and context params were not there - which explains why they were always empty. So, apologies for any presumptuousness, but it understandably looked like a bug.